# How to start a countdown timer event from the click of a button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, timer

so I have coded a timer where you are able to increase the hours, minutes and seconds by separate button click events. My aim was to set the hours, minutes and seconds and when I click a start button, the code will start to countdown. At the moment I can only seem to get the time to countdown as soon as the time is incremented. Anything I have tried has not worked with the start button click event, any idea's?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;
    TimeSpan countdownClock = TimeSpan.Zero;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = (int)TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds;
        timer.Tick += OnTimeEvent;
        DisplayTime();
    }
    private void DisplayTime()
    {
        lblTime.Text = countdownClock.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }
    private void OnTimeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Subtract whatever our interval is from the countdownClock
        countdownClock = countdownClock.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timer.Interval));

        if (countdownClock.TotalMilliseconds <= 0)
        {
            // Countdown clock has run out, so set it to zero 
            // (in case it's negative), and stop our timer
            countdownClock = TimeSpan.Zero;
            timer.Stop();
        }

        // Display the current time
        DisplayTime();
    }
    private void AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan timeToAdd)
    {
        // Add time to our clock
        countdownClock += timeToAdd;

        // Display the new time
        DisplayTime();

        // Start the timer if it's stopped
        if (!timer.Enabled) timer.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddTimeToClock(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    }

    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I have also tried adding a timer interval scale using this command

private static readonly int timeScale = 6

to adjust the countdownClock in the OnTimeEvent, and multiply by the scale.

countdownClock = countdownClock.Subtract(timeScale * TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timer.Interval));

Comment: is there a way of resetting all of the values once the timer has started by adding another button?

Comment: just do it in a new Click Event handler :)`
countdownClock = TimeSpan.Zero; and stop your timer

Comment: Thanks a lot, will give that a go!

Comment: Apologies for another question. I am now trying to play about with the time interval decrement so it countsdown quicker, does my code allow this?

Comment: yes it does :) just try

Comment: @TinoZ , I have been trying to scale the timer interval by a factor of 6  so for example 1hr = 10mins in real time but it is proving more difficult than it seems. Any chance you can help me out :)

Comment: update your question and i will hav look

Comment: Thank you, I have added the code to the bottom of the question where I changed the code

Comment: Any chance you had a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's your

```
// Start the timer if it's stopped
if (!timer.Enabled) timer.Start();
```

You are always starting your clock on time incrementation. Start your clock on btn click.